# Toastify Reactjs adding a link

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

How do I add a link like 'Click here to view' in reactjs toastify and link it to some other url?
Currently I can only add static text to it.
I used:

```
toast.info('some text')
```

And I want to display another line saying click here to view with a href property

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can toast with react components.

[Toast API](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/api/toast)

```
const CustomToastWithLink = () => (
  <div>
    <Link to="/toasttest">This is a link</Link>
  </div>
);
```

Toast by `toast.info(CustomToastWithLink);`

### React-Router v5

Example Usage

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

const CustomToastWithLink = () => (
  <div>
    <Link to="/toasttest">This is a link</Link>
  </div>
);

const Home = () => {
  const letsToast = () => {
    toast.info(CustomToastWithLink);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home</h3>
      <button type="button" onClick={letsToast}>
        Toast!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const ToastTest = () => (
  <div>
    <h3>Toast Test</h3>
    Toast Test Satisfactory
  </div>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/toasttest" component={ToastTest} />
          <Route component={Home} />
        </Switch>
        <ToastContainer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Custom Toastify Toast with React Component]

### React-Router v6

If you are using the RR6 *regular* routers then the pattern is exactly the same as RRv5, replacing `Switch` with the `Routes` component and using the correct `Route` props. If you are using the Data APIs though, e.g. `createBrowserRouter` then you'll need to create a layout route to provide the `ToastContainer` so it's rendered within a routing context.

Example:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Link,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";

const ToastProvider = () => (
  <>
    <Outlet />
    <ToastContainer />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <ToastProvider />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "toasttest",
        element: <ToastTest />
      },
      {
        path: "*",
        element: <Home />
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

```
<RouterProvider router={router} />
```

[image: Edit Custom Toastify Toast with React Component (forked)]